# jquery close element after element and re open new element

Tags: jquery, html

I have one big UL of inline list items containing input check boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/G3uyA/12/

Currently, at the moment I am trying to break it up into groups using jquery.

This is how it looks like before...

[image]

I'm trying to break it up into groups by adding in the string `</ul><ul class="gfield_checkbox checkbox">` after specific elements. So it looks like this:

[image]

But any jquery function that I use seems to add this string but modifies the string to complete elements and breaks my layout.

Here is my code:

```
function group_series() {

    var motogp = $('.gchoice_2_6_3');
    var sbk    = $('.gchoice_2_6_6');
    var road   = $('.gchoice_2_6_8');
    var mx     = $('.gchoice_2_6_13');

    $(motogp,sbk,road,mx).after('</ul><ul class="gfield_checkbox checkbox">');

};

$("#go").click(function() {
    group_series();
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to drop the html sting after each on off those elements that I declared as vars.

Can anyone please help of maybe off alternate cleaner solution?

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work because there isn't an element around it with an gform_2 id. Not the solution to your problem of course, but maybe helpful for anyone trying to test it

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, yeah that came across from my site. No it still turns my string into 2 elements and ignores the last two or three elems

Comment: Please include the HTML in your question, that way when, or if, JS Fiddle falls over, dies or reorganises its content the question remains useful to others in future.

Comment: I have now updated jsfiddle and question

Comment: But you haven't included the HTML in your question. Either the way it starts (before it's manipulated with jQuery/JavaScript) or *after* (what the HTML should be *after* it's been manipulated by jQuery/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid javascript entirely using some CSS3.

First switch to float rather than inline-block like below:

```
.gfield_checkbox > LI {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Then clear the float every 3.

```
.gfield_checkbox > LI:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear:both;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3uyA/10/)

Comment: Oo you don't know how much I would love to rely on CSS3 but my client and main users still using IE8. Any way, my grouping is very specific, not just every 3 elements. Thank you for idea tho.